# Spotify Android - how to stop app from hijacking headphones controls

Tags: android, controls, spotify-app

I am occasionally using Spotify on my Android phone. But mostly I am listening to stuff on Youtube or Rumble (web version via Brave browser, NOT app), so as not to pay YT for premium but still have playback with screen off. Spotify is also configured to play with screen off.

For that I'm using bluetooth headphones and BT in my car.

All was working fine until i started using Spotify. Since then it happens very often that I am listening to something on YT (via Brave), with screen off, but with Brave being on foregound, and playback stops (there are various reasons for that, like exiting a car).

Then, when clicking play/pause button on headphones, Spotify's last played track starts, instead of YT track that was playing just seconds ago. I closed the Spotify app before that, so logically this should not happen. I have an app for audiobook playback, which behaves similarly, but it has an "Exit" option in it's menu, so all good.

How to stop Spotify from hijacking the playback controls of BT device?